# Will the Braintree JavaScript API work ok for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone, braintree

I have been reviewing Braintree for an app I may be developing. I was wondering if I could use the JavaScript API to utilize Braintree on a Windows Phone 8.1 HTML / CSS / JS Runtime app(since there is no official Windows Phone API). Would I run into any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Braintree. We have had merchants report success with a Windows Phone 8.1 application based on our web libraries, however we don't have any specific guides to share with you. If you encounter issues we'd be glad to take a look (your best bet may be to [contact our support team](http://support.braintreepayments.com/)) and see if there is anything we can do to help.